# Angular - Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing an client portal application. Laravel-5.8 is the backend and Angular-7 is the frontend. I am using a POST REQUEST.

client-quote-landing.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientQuoteService } from '../../../../shared/services/client-quote.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-client-quote-landing',
 templateUrl: './client-quote-landing.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./client-quote-landing.component.scss']
})
export class ClientQuoteLandingComponent implements OnInit {

quoteModel: any = {};
formattedAddress = '';
truck_types = [];

constructor(
private clientQuoteService: ClientQuoteService, private toastr: ToastrService,
private router: Router,
@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,
private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
 }

ngOnInit() {
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
```

client-quote-landing.component.html

```
 <form name="quote" #quoteform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreateQuote(quoteform);" method="post" novalidate>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <label for="loading_date">Loading Date<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
   <div class="input-group date">
   <mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker] = "picker" placeholder = "Choose a date" name="loading_date" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.loading_date" #loading_date="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || quoteform.submitted)}"   required>
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   </mat-form-field>
   <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || quoteform.submitted)">
   <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="loading_date.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Loading Date is required.</div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <button style="margin:5px"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > Get A Quote</button>
  </form>
```

When I clicked on the submit button, nothing was happening, then I checked the network and I got this error:

> message: "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2019-09-26T23:00:00.000Z' for column `clientportal`.`client_quotes`.`loading_date` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `client_quotes` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`, `business_name`, `address`, `comment`, `truck_type`, `truck_required`, `quote_origin`, `quote_destination`, `commodity`, `loading_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Michael, Idowu, noblemfd@yahoo.com, 33334444444444, jolamic, ddsds, dd, Residential, 2, ddds, ssa, ee, 2019-09-26T23:00:00.000Z, 2019-09-19 00:53:55, 2019-09-19 00:53:55))"

In MySQL database, **loading_date** datatype is date.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

change **loading_date**  data type to **varchar(20)**, The error is because you chose the wrong data type.

Comment: But loading_date is date. That means I will need to convert it from string to date

Comment: The error is on  clientportal, client_quotes, loading_date fields, change thsese fields data type to varchar and test it out again.

Comment: @ sajad Haibat  - loading_date is the only field. clientportal and client_quotes are just the path.  clientpotal/client_quotes/loading_date